# Unable to get currently connected WiFi supported encryption type information

Tags: android, encryption

i am using the below code for retrieving connected wifi encryption type,

**Code snippet:**

```
        List<WifiConfiguration> wifiConfigs = wifiMgr.getConfiguredNetworks();

        if (wifiConfigs != null && wifiConfigs.size() > 0) {
            for (WifiConfiguration config : wifiConfigs) {
                if (config != null && ssid.equalsIgnoreCase(config.SSID)) {

                    if (config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK)) {
                        encryptionType.append("WPA_PSK");
                    }
                    if (config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP)) {
                        encryptionType.append(" WPA_EAP");
                    }
                    if (config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X)) {
                        encryptionType.append(" IEEE8021X");
                    } else {
                        if (config.wepKeys[0] != null) {
                            return "WEP";
                        } else {
                            return "NONE";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem:** In android device, currently connected WiFi access point is showing encryption type as "802.1x EAP(CCKM)". But the above code, always returns "NONE" as result.

How can I get actual value through android code(probably using WifiConfiguration).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to get the encryption types supported by wifi access point(currently connected by android mobile device) by below code,

```
List<WifiConfiguration> wifiConfigs = wifiMgr.getConfiguredNetworks();
if (wifiConfigs != null && wifiConfigs.size() > 0) {
    for (WifiConfiguration config : wifiConfigs) {
      if (config != null && ssid.equalsIgnoreCase(config.SSID)) {
        for (int k = 0; k < config.allowedKeyManagement.size(); k++) {
           if (config.allowedKeyManagement.get(k)) {
               encryptionType.append(" ");
               if (k < KeyMgmt.strings.length) {
                   encryptionType.append(KeyMgmt.strings[k]);
                     }
                   }
               }
           }
        }
     }
```

Hope this helps you.